# ListViewItem access property on viewmodel

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a list of users on my viewmodel that I pass to the following listView:

```
                  <ListView
                  Background="Azure"
                  x:Name="ContactList"                  
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=User}"                 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Border Width="300" Height="Auto" BorderThickness="1">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBlock>
                                    <Run Text="{Binding Name}" />                            
                                    <Run Text="{Binding Age}" />
                                        </TextBlock>
                                        <CheckBox Visibility="{???}">
                                            <TextBlock FlowDirection="LeftToRight"></TextBlock>
                                        </CheckBox>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>                              
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

As you can see my `DataTemplate` contains a `checkbox`. I would like its Visibility to depend on a bool-property I have on my ViewModel. How can I access this property from within the listView?

From looking around here it seems like there are ways to access the ListView-items parent. I think that would do it for me. Can someone point me in the right direction . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to include the visibility setting along with your user data. Assuming your view model visibility property is named `CheckBoxVisibility`, you would have something like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" ...>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            ...
                <Run Text="{Binding Path=User.Name}" />
                <Run Text="{Binding Path=User.Age}" />
            ...
            <CheckBox Visibility="{Binding Path=CheckBoxVisibility}">
            ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In WPF, you can use a RelativeSource=RelativeAncestor binding; however, this is not available in Window Store/Windows Phone 8+ apps.

Comment: Thank you! I´ll go with this way.